# Cannot login with the Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I have a problem when I try to login to Firebase using the CLI. I installed `firebase-tools` using `npm -g install firebase-tools` with admin rights. The steps I do are (from a cygwin terminal on Windows 10 Professional):

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

After this I get the message:

```
Visit the URL on any device....
Paste authentication code here:
```

Then, on my browser, I see Google asking if I give Firebase CLI access rights, I say yes and then I get an authorization code displayed on the browser.

I copy this code into the cygwin console and then:

```
Error: Authentication Error.
```

I'm at a total loss for this and it's completely stalling my efforts to get to know Firebase. All help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
firebase login --interactive
```

it will open up a browser window to authenticate.

Answer (score 4):

In my case was bug in terminal in Visual Studio Code. On CMD terminal it start works.

Answer (score 4):

I copy pasted the link into an incognito window, and somehow it worked.

Answer (score 1):

On windows 10, I had issues with my firebase login through cli. I had to run my command line as the administrator and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

After running across this problem I tried multiple different things to solve this:

1. Used firebase login --reauth
2. Used firebase login --no-localhost
3. Turned off proxy settings
4. Ran command from within windows/system32
5. Turned off my security settings in Firefox

All these options listed above worked for others but not for me

Finally the way it worked was to install google chrome and run the command from from chrome instead of firefox

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Mac and solved running firebase login with sudo

```
sudo firebase login
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today and it was because back in the day I used firebase and didn't remove this define from my bash_profile

FIREBASE_TOKEN

try echo $FIREBASE_TOKEN if something shows up try deleting, open new terminal and re-authenticating

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

my FIREBASE_TOKEN was FIREBASE_TOKEN=' '. I logged out of all my terminal sessions and tried again and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the cmd wit administrator privilege...! Happy coding

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/63810360/1364007

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't log in with firebase CLI using the **"firebase login"** command

Then, use [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) instead of **PowerShell** in the VS code or any other code editor terminal.
First, download [Git SCM](https://git-scm.com/downloads) then use gitbash in the terminal for any kind of **Firebase hosting** command [terminal image using gitBash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqh3h.png)

It does work actually!!

Answer (score 0):

I used with cmd, it was worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your firebase version. if firebase version is "8.15.0" this, then its okay, if not: uninstall firebase-tools globally and globally install it again with 'version'

`npm i --global firebase-tools@8.15.0`

then after check which terminal u r using, make sure to use cmd terminal. go to your directory and fire command

`firebase login`.

Check if its working

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution from github and it worked for me. I am using linux/ubuntu and I disabled IPv6.

This method edits a system configuration file to disable IPv6. The changes are temporary, but they persist until the system is rebooted.

Here's how to disable IPv6:Open a terminal window.
Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file with a text editor by running:

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Save and close the file.

Apply the changes with:

`sudo sysctl -p`

Verify if IPv6 is disabled by running:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`

If the output is `1`, IPv6 is disabled.
When you are done

Continue with

`firebase login`

And you will get this output

`✔  Success! Logged in as`