# Authorization error on GCP when trying firebase login remotely from a CLI: Error 400: invalid_request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I am trying to do:

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

After I connect to the GCP remote server (using terminal Cygwin64 on Win11). I am getting an authentication address on the CLI that I should paste into my browser. It starts with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id="
After pasting this address on my browser I get:

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request
The version of the app you're using doesn't include the latest security features to keep you protected. Please make sure to download from a trusted source and update to the latest, most secure version.
```

I have installed the dirsync-win64.exe and installed on my PC which should get me the latest update for my understanding, but the result is the same.
Note that I have a paying user account on GCP.
I read somewhere there were security updates by GCP, and I may need to change the user type, but I see that I am already the owner of both GCP and the Firebase.
p.s. first few times I tried without the --localhost but when I pasted the address above, it first directed me to choose the Google user for login, then after choosing it I got to approve the Firebase CLI access to my account, and after I approved I got this error:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can refer the links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899109/cannot-login-with-the-firebase-cli?rq=1  and  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#update-cli   .
Also check the useful update here.
https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html